# Find country a tweet is from - if Geo location is disabled

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to fine country a tweet is from - if Geo location is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing we can do except guessing with user specified location (can be hell,heaven,universe too) and language